# Angular TypeError: Cannot create property on string ''

Tags: angularjs

Trying to clear the input box after Add is clicked, like the guy is doing in  [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/iFsYJG3fGro?t=16m37s).
I have recreated the error without using the API, with this short code.
You can also check out the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kKMm7GkkDrDhcLjIaPv2?p=preview).

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="contact.name" type="text">
<button ng-click="Add()">Add</button>

<ul ng-repeat="contact in contactList">
    <li>{{ contact.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.contactList = [
    {name: 'cris'}, {name: 'vlad'}
;]

$scope.Add = function() {
    $scope.contactList.push($scope.contact)
    $scope.contact = ""
}
```

It seems that i can add 1 item, but on the second i get this Error:
[image]

Comment: Your code is working fine check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9418/. Tell me the exact scenario of the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You didn't clean your `contact` object the right way. In the `Add()` function, change:

```
$scope.contact = ""
```

To:

```
$scope.contact = {};
```

### [Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3v7PMw8Nge80Dh6sZ40h?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I guess the problem was, I changing the `contact` Object type to a string?

Comment: @Cris Exactly. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the $scope.contact property to a string here:

```
$scope.contact = ""
```

In your template you are binding to contact.name here:

```
<input ng-model="contact.name" type="text" class="form-control">
```

a string does not have the property "name", hence the error. A fix would be to do this:

```
$scope.contact = { name: "" }
```

This creates a new object with the property "name" and an empty string as the value of that property.

Comment: yes, happened with me. conflicting names from ng-repeat and scope vars in controller. thanks